# how to limit fetch from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

an example table in database mysql,

```
id alphabet
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
```

My project require me to fetch 26 array from the database.
Is there a way to limit my output to 1 without limit it cause i want to display eg: A,
then by pressing a button, if it meet the requirement, it will then display B?

Comment: What does "limit my output to 1 without limit it" mean? Do you want to limit it or don't you?

Comment: i mean i want i need to read all the data in the database but i want to display only the A from the database, then by click it then will read B from the database.

Comment: You could use ajax to run another query when they're ready to press B

Comment: You can use a pure PHP solution like my answer. Or you could use CSS and Javascript. Have the PHP print all the rows, but with `visibility: hidden` for all rows except A. The `onclick` action of the button would then change visibility of A to `hidden` and B to `visibility: visible`.  Each time you click, it moves the visible property to the next row. This is much faster, since it doesn't require a trip to the server. But it won't work for users who disable Javascript, and if the table is large it means a much slower first hit.

Comment: i am using ecmascript...

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server, it can't respond directly to user clicks. Each time the user clicks on a link to the page, the script starts fresh.

The first time the script runs, you can run the query and save all the results in a session variable (called `array_data` in the example below). You can then make the button link to the script with a parameter that tells it which row number to display. Something like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['array_data'])) {
  $_SESSION['array_data'] = array();
  <execute query>
  while ($row = <fetch row>) $_SESSION['array_data'][] = $row;
}
$cur_row = isset($_REQUEST['rowid']) ? $_REQUEST['rowid'] : 0;
printf("Data is: %s<BR/>", htmlentities($_SESSION['array_data'][$cur_row]));
printf("<A HREF='scriptname.php?rowid=%d'>Next row</A>", $cur_row+1);
```

Comment: nice extrapolation and solution of poorly asked question %)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` in SQL to limit the number of results that you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a shoot in the dark here with your question.  Using the LIMIT and OFFSET can help you retrieve a single row.

```
SELECT id, alphabet FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

LIMIT 1 will always give you one record.  The OFFSET says how many rows to skip.

[LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use a FOR(){} loop.
Ex:

```
for($i; $i < 1; $i++){

$DoSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <database> ORDER BY ABS(<datarow>) asc");
$FetchSql = mysql_fetch_array($DoSql);

---Your code goes Here---

}
```